# Array not displaying proper value after push in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my app i want to push some element to array after verifying. I just compare two string if its same then i will push it to an array. If i save that string in var and display its work fine but in array its shows wrongly.
If i type a in text box it will show all the names with A and for Ab it shows all the names with starts with A.

```
     $( document ).ready(function() {
     var vendornames =["Abac","Abrs","aspc","Asrp","betd","gtser","gdrt"]
     var list = new Array();

     $('#vendor-name').keyup(function(event){

        var $textValue = $(this).val();
        if ($textValue.length > 0) {

            jQuery.each(vendornames, function (i, val) {

                if (val.indexOf($textValue) === 0) {
                    list.push(val);
                  }
            });
        }

      alert(list)
    });
```

Comment: you should read my answer on your latest post, the array was initialized in the callback function, not global to the scope. you have to reset the array `list` at the beginning of the callback, like `list = [];` before doing `var $textValue = ...`

Comment: A comment on coding style; either use semi colons everywhere or don't ... mixed style is distracting to read.

Comment: also need to compare both using same case, convert both values to lower case or upper since `a` won't match `A`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code for what you are trying to achieve, not sure about whatever you are looking for case insensitive solution or not, but this will work as per the input compared with array values

```
    ;(function() {
     var vendornames =["Abac","Abrs","aspc","Asrp","betd","gtser","gdrt"],
         list = [],
         targetEle = "#vendor-name";

    $(targetEle).on("keyup", function(event){
     var $textValue = $(this).val();
        if($textValue.length >= 3){
            $.map( vendornames, function( n ) {
                        return n == $textValue ? list.push(n) : null;
                    }); 
            console.clear();
            console.table(list);
            }
    });     
})();
```